# How to turn on led/beep sound at zk4500 fingerprint scanner?

Tags: c#, fingerprint

According to c++ sample we can turn on beep sound/led light using `ControlSensor`

```
void CDemoDlg::OnBnClickedBtngreen()
{
    zkfpEng.ControlSensor(11, 1);
    Sleep(100);
    zkfpEng.ControlSensor(11, 0);
}

void CDemoDlg::OnBnClickedBtnbeep()
{
    zkfpEng.ControlSensor(13, 1);
    Sleep(100);
    zkfpEng.ControlSensor(13, 0);
}
```

but I can't find this method in libzkfpcsharp.dll (native dll from zkteco). The only thing I found is SetParameters/GetParameters. I have tryied to set parametrs, but it didn't work:

```
byte[] paramValue1 = new byte[4];
int size = 4;
zkfp.Int2ByteArray(1, paramValue1);
zkfp2.SetParameters(mDBHandle, 102, paramValue1, size);
```

C# SDK pdf says:

[image]

Comment: Though I haven't used this library, my guess is `C++` can interact with the hardware directly, but not `C#`, so you'll have to figure out some alternative for that

Comment: @o_O no doubts, c++ code works perfect. But still I can get data from device using GetParameters(IntPtr devHandle, int code, byte[] paramValue, ref int size); and to grab device serial number, image resolution, etc...

Comment: It's not about `GetParameters`, but `SetParameters`; I faced similar problem while using some other library for barcode scanning, where some `C++` fixes solved the issue.. I maybe wrong and sorry can't help you. Maybe someone else will

Answer (score 0):

I've found it!;

```
byte[] paramValue1 = new byte[4];
zkfp.Int2ByteArray(1, paramValue1);
zkfp2.SetParameters(mDevHandle, 102, paramValue1, 4);
Thread.Sleep(200);
zkfp.Int2ByteArray(0, paramValue1);
zkfp2.SetParameters(mDevHandle, 102, paramValue1, 4);
```

I've made like that and it works!